# How to make multiple lights non-additive in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to get a model working which has 8 different light sources. I would like to make it so that a surface reaches its "maximum" value when near one light source, but the way the code works now if multiple lights are near a surface, it just keeps increasing in how lit up it is until it is almost pure-white.

For surfaces, I use:

```
float white[] = {1,1,1,1};
float black[] = {0,0,0,1};
float medium[] = {.5,.5,.5,.5};
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_SPECULAR,white);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_EMISSION,black);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_DIFFUSE,medium);
```

And for the eight lights:

```
    int glLightConstant = GL_LIGHT0 + i;

    float Diffuse[]   = {(float)0.01*50 ,(float)0.01*50 ,(float)0.01*50 ,1.0f};
    float Specular[]  = {(float)0.01*0,(float)0.01*0,(float)0.01*0,1.0f};
    float Position[]  = {(float)positions[i].x,(float)positions[i].y,(float)positions[i].z,(float)1.0};

    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER,0.0);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(glLightConstant);
    if(i == 0) {
        float Ambient[]   = {(float)0.01*0 ,(float)0.01*0 ,(float)0.01*0 ,1.0f};
        glLightfv(glLightConstant,GL_AMBIENT ,Ambient);
    }
    glLightfv(glLightConstant,GL_DIFFUSE ,Diffuse);
    glLightfv(glLightConstant,GL_SPECULAR,Specular);
    glLightfv(glLightConstant,GL_POSITION,Position);
```

I realize that the ambient light is 0, I might change it later.

Comment: @J.Doe: "*I would like to make it so that a surface reaches its "maximum" value when near one light source*" That's not how light works. In reality, light doesn't have a "maximum value". You don't stop getting brighter when you approach the sun.

Comment: You could clamp the value if it is so desirable